# How to make content creation form more organized. Taxonomy Checkbox list

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I am preparing to allow users to edit specific fields of content. I have until now used autocomplete for myself.

I would like to start using the Check boxes, but as of right now it show my 30 terms as a one column list.

Is there a way to have these terms show in 4 columns instead of one long column. (to organize it better and utilize page space)

Comment: Use CSS to change the layout of that field

Comment: How do i use CSS To make one column turn into 3 or 4 i think that is HTML

Comment: Did the answer below help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with using CSS to change the layout of your drupal site already, something like this should work:

/* Make categories field 2 columns */

div.form-item.form-type-checkboxes.form-item-field-categories-und {

```
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 20px;
```

}

If not, it will depend on what theme you are using. We are using the seven theme for our admin pages, which include the node create pages. In the seven theme, I could just add the chunk of CSS above to the style.css file. Technically however, this chunk probably shouldn't be added into a core theme because it might get wiped out when/if you upgrade drupal core.

If you want to do it properly, you should create a new stylesheet with something similar to the CSS chunk above and give it a name. Then, add that stylesheet in your theme's .info file. (You can see specific instructions on how to do that here: https://drupal.org/node/171209)

Be sure that you don't have your CSS optimized when you are updating your stylesheets. If you aren't sure how to check this setting, go to admin/config/development/performance and make sure the option to aggregate and compress CSS isn't checked.

Without knowing more about your setup, what theme you are using, etc. it's hard to make a more specific recommendation.

Comment: Thanks! just what i needed. I never new i could do columns with CSS. All is good. =-)